# Can anyone suggest how can I edit hosts file using adb?

Tags: android, adb

getting errors while running push command and unable to enter in root mode.

```
:\Users\...>adb push "C:\Users\...Desktop\platform-tools_r33.0.2-windows\platform-tools\hosts" /system/etc/
C:\Users\...ools\hosts: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 0.0 MB/s (188 bytes in 30.981s)
adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Users\...tools\hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system


m31s:/etc $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found
m31s:/etc $ vi hosts
/system/bin/sh: vi: inaccessible or not found

127|m31s:/etc $ nano hosts
/system/bin/sh: nano: inaccessible or not found

127|m31s:/etc $ gedit hosts
/system/bin/sh: gedit: inaccessible or not found

#unable to root mode
C:\Users\...tools>adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

Comment: From the error messages you get, it seems like you cannot do this unless you root the phone.

Comment: You device seems to be not rooted but a rooted device is required to modify the Android hosts file. What do you want to do?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a standard Android phone because of security restrictions. The only way to do it is to root your phone.